# Angular 7 gives this.interceptor is undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to implement a HTTP Interceptor in angular7, but it gives "this.interceptor is undefined" error. What is the reason for it?

auth.service.ts - where i make http call

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService{

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    login(userName, password){
        return this.httpClient.post('/authenticate', {"username" : userName, "password" : password});
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, fakeBackendProvider],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

interceptor

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpInterceptor,  HttpHandler, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';

class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      const { url, method, headers, body } = request;
      return next.handle(request);
   }

}

export const fakeBackendProvider = {
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useFactory: FakeBackendInterceptor,
   multi: true
}
```

This is the error i get,

[image: console error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interceptors need to be *provided* differently in the module:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: FakeBackendProvider,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Make sure to import `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` from `@angular/common/http`. More info on interceptors and how to *provide* them can be found in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses).